# Jquery Issue with full calendar and mega menu

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Can anyone say why this megamenu isnt working when i hover categories menu on this page? it works on other pages, but in this page its not because of fullcalendar??

http://gunwebstaging.com.mytempweb.com/Calendar.aspx

Comment: The hover panels don't work for you? What browswer are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about megamenu, but I have hover panels working here:

http://obpk.com/fc/ex/fc.html

Comment: Well it doesnt work actually im getting a javascript error saying object not supported this method ??